# Symfony2 Error Positioning is wrong

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.5

I am using the FOSUserBundle to register users. The errors are appearing in an odd place though.

They are appearing within the Password field row, not the username or email

[image: form errors]

As you can see the errors are rendered next to Password and not Username nor Email. The HTML shows that the errors are within the Password row and not just at the bottom of the Username row.

Why is this?

I have used `fields.html.twig` and added this;

```
{% block form_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="form-group">           
            {{ form_errors(form) }}         
            {{ form_label(form) }}
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}
```

This works but the errors are all appearing within the password `form-group` div.

The view file looks like this within `Resources/views/Registration/register_content.html.twig`

```
<form role="form" action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="form-horizontal fos_user_registration_register">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I move them into their respective divs or move them to the start of the form?

I also have this validation.yml file, which might be note worthy

```
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: {fields: username, message: "This username is taken" }
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: {fields: email, message: "This email is taken" }
```

Comment: The look of the page and positioning of elements is controlled by a template. Show your template file for this page.

Comment: Which version of FOSUserBundle are you using (2.x@dev or 1.x)?

Comment: `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",`

Comment: I even tried moving to 1.3 but its the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug with validation groups in the current Symfony **2.5** which drove me crazy. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150574/symfony-2-forms-with-validation-groups-errors-mapped-to-the-wrong-property). You can fix this by enforcing the prior validation API in your `config.yml`:

```
framework:
    validation:
        enable_annotations: true
        api: 2.4 # default is auto which sets broken API 2.5
```

All cudos to @gremo for saving my sanity.

Comment: Glad to help... btw: It's a good idea to add the used Symfony version as a question tag, so it's easier to spot such issues :)

Answer (score 1):

`{{ form_errors(form) }}` renders errors that are attached to a form. And they are shown at the place where `{{ form_errors(form) }}` is mentioned last time, which is inside `password` `div`.

It looks like you have `error_bubbling` set to true for your form fields. If you want errors to be shown next to elements, do not use `error_bubbling`.

Also, you can render fields individually inside your `Resources/views/Registration/register_content.html.twig` template. I would remove `fields.html.twig` and change `Resources/views/Registration/register_content.html.twig` to the following:

```
<form role="form" action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="form-horizontal fos_user_registration_register">

    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
        {{ form_label(form.email) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
        {{ form_label(form.username) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.username) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
        </div>
    </div>

    {{ form_rest(form) }}

</form>
```

Comment: I've just got around to trying it. Even without turning bubbling off the errors still only appear with the first Password fields. How would I turn bubbling off for the FOS User Bundle forms?

Comment: I've also added my `validation.yml` file, which I don't think is having an affect. But might be worth showing.

Comment: error_bubbling isn't turned on for the FOSUserBundle registration form  and defaults to false so shouldn't be on.

Comment: Also your thinking on the `form_errors(form)` issue is incorrect. When you use `form_row(form.something)`, a twig extension calls a method called `form_row` and then passes `form.something` to the `form_row` block but with the variable name `form`, so the form errors being called would be for `form.something` not the whole form. It's just like if you had a function like `function doSomething($form)`  and then called it like `$form = array('a' => 'b'); doSomething($form['a'])`, the value of $form inside the function would be `b` rather than the original array.